# import the image folder to my program using python and opencv2?

Tags: python, list, opencv, dataset

I am working on color based image classification and retrieval using image mining technique, using python and opencv, 
what i have done is, i have taken a dataset and stored 100 images in a list, then resize it, code:

```
import cv2
from numpy import *
import os
import glob
path = 'C:\Users\HP\Desktop\dataset1'
B_mean = list()
G_mean = list()
R_mean = list()
piclist = list()
graylist = list()
resizelist = list()
for infile in glob.glob(os.path.join(path,'*.jpg')):
   imge = cv2.imread(infile)
   arr = array(imge)
   piclist.append(imge)
   re_img = cv2.resize(imge,(200,200))
   *g_img = cv2.imread(re_img)
   gray_scale = cv2.cvtColor(g_img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
   graylist.append(gray_scale)*
   resizelist.append(re_img)
   blue, green, red = cv2.split(re_img)
   total = re_img.size
   B = sum(blue) / total
   G = sum(green) / total
   R = sum(red) / total
   B_mean.append(B)
   G_mean.append(G)
   R_mean.append(R)
```

but the problem is i am not able to convert the images in the 'resizelist' to grayscale, 
the error is:

```
E:\Canopy\programs\demo\loading_image_from_folder1.py in <module>()
 17     image = resizelist[i]
 18     arr1 = array(image)
 ---> 19     gray = cv2.imread(image,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
 20     graylist.append(gray)
```

TypeError: expected string or Unicode object, numpy.ndarray found

i am using list because it is mutable or do i have to use any other??

Thanks for the support in advance!

Comment: unclear problem .. "now i am stuck while importing an image data set to my script."   <-- that means what ?

Comment: "suggest me, what i can do". My suggestion is to make a more clear question, possible showing what you have tried, and any specific problems encountered etc.

Comment: Which images? Which image format? What have you tried/found? What is the Error&Traceback? What is your code? Which operating system? Which sizes are the images? Have you installed everything? Can you refine your question? Otherwise we can not help you.

Comment: Your error seems to be from different code than what you have shared

Comment: No no,this is what i have been working on.. I'm using Enthought canopy to run this program.